# Ruby 2.5.1, Rails 5.1.6, HTTParty post returns OpenSSL error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, httparty

I am running a console utility, I've tried verified:false, just to determine if its'a a client or a server issue, when I run this:

Comment: Would you be able to provide the output of  `openssl s_client -connect your-url:443 -ssl3`? Also after updating openssl, did you reinstall ruby to pick up the new openssl version? (If not - it might help)

Comment: @ViktorNonov i get this  openssl s_client -connect your-url:443 -ssl3
s_client: Option unknown option -ssl3
s_client: Use -help for summary.

Comment: okay. New versions of openssl don't have ssl3 included by default (since it's insecure), I suspect that you need to reinstall ruby so it can pick your updated openssl. Run this in the rails console `require 'openssl'; OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION` and compare to `openssl version` ran in bash. If the versions are different reinstall ruby.

Comment: console output:  OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017  command line output OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information in the comments I seems that the client and the server can't negotiate which cryptographic protocol to use.

In order to fix this you might need to do one of the following things:

- You can try to use specific ssl version on the request:

  ```
  HTTParty.post(url, body: payload.to_json, ssl_version: :TLSv1)
  ```

You can find all supported `:ssl_versions` values by using `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::METHODS` in the rails console and try to use some of them.

- If the server does support only SSLv3 (which is [not secure](https://disablessl3.com/)), you might need to [rebuild openssl](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) with ssl3 support on your machine or if you have access to the server to set it up so it supports more secure protocols.

Comment: thanks for your help viktor, it turns out the site was set up with multiple apache configs, removing the deprecated ones fixed the issue, but your suggestion worked

Answer (score 0):

In my case was founded that need to decrease security level `ciphers: "DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1"` because of destination server is using the old protocol TLS 1.0